# Best place to start learning how to setup a WebServer?

Tags: apache-2.2, ftp

I want to start making my own Web Server that uses Apache and a simple FTP server from scratch but dont know where to start, I already know lots of PHP and SQL but want to expand my knowledge in this topic. Might I add, I have never learned anything computer from reading a book or videos (Except when I started learning Java). Where to start?

Answer (score 1):

[HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/) is another great resource - you can find detailed tutorials for just about every Linux distribution.

If you're using Windows, however, you'll probably have better luck with [WAMPServer.com](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Slicehost have some great beginner [tutorials](http://articles.slicehost.com/) - why not start there? Select your distribution from the Distros column and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Books and online sources can help, but if you're like me you won't learn if you can't get your hands dirty.

Set up a Linux box on your LAN, arranged so you can shell into it with ssh and browse it from your workstation, and start messing with it, looking up questions as they occur to you and solving problems as you install stuff and try things out. That box must NOT be visible from the Internet; that way you can try things out without embarrassment and without getting r00t3d (or busted for running nmap and exploit-scanners against your own equipment). If you don't currently have a LAN, here's your reason to establish one. That box can be old-and-slow, because the only callers it'll ever see are the folks on your LAN, so, if it takes it a few seconds to serve a MediaWiki page (it was 2-4 seconds on my Pentium 133 running Slackware), nobody's complaining.

When you're far enough along for it to matter, that Linux machine will become your development and staging server, so nothing but known-working pages are posted to a Net-facing server. Right now, though, it's your playground and schoolroom.